# How to register constraint configurations under different reuse identifiers.and Auto layout suggestions.

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, uitableview

My custom cell scrolling in table view is very choppy.

I have a custom cell which looks some what like the image attached. 
Each of the coloured views are complex views (has many subviews in them).

I have added constraints for each view and at `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I change the constraint.constant values to show the view based on the data i need to show. I also change the width constraint of the views depending on the data i need to show.

The reason i chose this approach was because the middle yellow view can be *one of six* views all having this base configuration. I initialise a the view add it as a child of yellow view and pin the child view to this yellow parent view.

Many of these views get hidden / unhidden based on the data provided. For that i change the width / height constraint to zero.

I have used different reuse identifiers for all the 6 views that the yellow view can hold, this way I don't end up re-initialising them always.

My scroll performance is very choppy. I profiled the app and I see most of my CPU is used for AutoLayout system calls like updateConstraintsNecessary etc.

Please help with .
1) suggesting how to reduce the autolayout calls in table view scrolling for smooth scrolling. 
2) according to this https://www.prolificinteractive.com/2015/08/19/troubleshooting-table-view-performance/ - How to register constraint configurations under different reuse identifiers without making new Nib's because all views in the picture below except the yellow are common.

Reference picture - 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way. Moved away from the XIB, had just a .h and a .m.

I am currently using

```
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style 
              reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
```

With this I get a way to only have those constraints / views inited which I need for a reuse identifier and not having to change constraints at runtime.